# Restrict drag and drop for custom panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I created custom control with panel as base class in windows C#.

Now, I want to restrict the custom control designer to restrict the drag and drop other controls.

How I can achive this functionalty?

Answer (score 0):

```
[System.ComponentModel.Designer(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner))]
public class MyPanel
{
}
```

Each control has a designer class assigned to it which tells windows forms desginer how to treat it at design-time. Panel is a container control and its designer allows dropping other controls into it. The above code changes your control's designer to a simple designer (such as label's) which does not support containing other controls (droping them in at design time).